# What can I use for transfering hierarchical object for GWT RPC with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, gwt, gwt-rpc, gilead

I heard that Gilead was a fine solution but it isn't suppoerted already.

What is the best current solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at RequestFactory? In combination with the Editor framework it is pretty slick. You get features like JSR-303 support, automatic fetch paths, only sending delta updates, binding to/from Editors...

Quite a lot to learn up front but I think it is worth the effort.